# Creating a dynamic Pydantic model from a JSON schema with field validators

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic, pydantic-v2

I am working on a project where I need to dynamically generate Pydantic models in Python using JSON schemas. These models should include field validators specified within the JSON schema. I want to store the JSON schema in a MongoDB database and retrieve it as needed to create the Pydantic models dynamically. I have attempted to implement a solution, but I am facing some challenges with the implementation.

Here's an example of what I have tried:

```py
class UserModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    id: int

    @field_validator('name')
    @classmethod
    def name_must_contain_space(cls, v: str) -> str:
        if ' ' not in v:
            raise ValueError('Name must contain a space')
        return v.title()
```

I want to be able to convert this into a JSON Schema and directly convert the model from the json schema to the above. I have been able to just make the variables as a dynamic model but have not been able to add the `field_validators` bit into a json.
I want to be able to do something like the below

```py
def create_dynamic_model_from_schema(schema_data):
    fields = {}
    for field_name, field_data in schema_data.items():
        field_type = field_data.get("type", str)
        validators = field_data.get("@field_validator", [])
        
        # Add validators to the field
        field = Field(..., title=field_name)
        for validator in validators:
            field = validator(field)
        
        fields[field_name] = (field_type, field)

    return create_model("DynamicModel", **fields)

DynamicModel = create_dynamic_model_from_schema(schema_data)
```

Additionally, I'm not sure if this approach is the most efficient or best practice for dynamically generating models with Pydantic.

Could someone guide how to properly store the JSON schema in MongoDB and retrieve it to create dynamic Pydantic models with field validators? Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/koxudaxi/datamodel-code-generator/ already?

Comment: That looks to have the same problem, if I am not mistaken that it cannot generate that function code on the go?